# PHP: return value of user selected array

Tags: php, arrays, concrete5

please excuse this if its a duplicate or similar post, i have searched on here and could not figure out the answer to my question based on previous posts...

I know this may be a noob question (im trying desperately to teach myself php so please bear with me!)

I have a custom concrete5 block I am building (using jordanlev's awesome designer content).

Here is the code:

```
<?php  if ($field_3_select_value == 1): ?>
<!-- ENTER MARKUP HERE FOR FIELD "Heading Placement Left or Right?" : CHOICE "head-left" -->

<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if ($field_3_select_value == 2): ?>
<!-- ENTER MARKUP HERE FOR FIELD "Heading Placement Left or Right?" : CHOICE "head-right" -->
<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if ($field_4_select_value == 1): ?>
<!-- ENTER MARKUP HERE FOR FIELD "Heading Placement - top middle bottom" : CHOICE "top" -->
<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if ($field_4_select_value == 2): ?>
<!-- ENTER MARKUP HERE FOR FIELD "Heading Placement - top middle bottom" : CHOICE "middle" -->
<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if ($field_4_select_value == 3): ?>
<!-- ENTER MARKUP HERE FOR FIELD "Heading Placement - top middle bottom" : CHOICE "bottom" -->
<?php  endif; ?>

<div class="span 7 head <?php echo $field_3_select_value->$value; ?> <?php echo $field_4_select_value->$value; ?>">

<?php  if (!empty($field_6_textbox_text)): ?>
<h2><?php  echo htmlentities($field_6_textbox_text, ENT_QUOTES, APP_CHARSET); ?></h2>
<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if (!empty($field_7_textbox_text)): ?>
<h2><?php  echo htmlentities($field_7_textbox_text, ENT_QUOTES, APP_CHARSET); ?></h2>
<?php  endif; ?>

<?php  if (!empty($field_8_textbox_text)): ?>    
<h2><?php  echo htmlentities($field_8_textbox_text, ENT_QUOTES, APP_CHARSET); ?></h2>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

What im trying to achieve is the value of `$field_3_select_value` & `$field_4_select_value` to appear as the content of the array in the class of the DIV.

Next up i have 3 text boxes that get inserted (if filled in by user) that is styled according to the classes on the div above.

Is this possible? Do i need to build a 'foreach' loop and if so, can someone help point me in the right direction? I would prefer to learn how to do this rather than just someone do it for me, so any help and any direction and of course any constructive criticism is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What strikes me as odd on this is that in the comparisons it appears as though the $field_x_select_value would contain an integer but there is also references to $field_x_select_value->$value; I think what you want to echo here is $field_3_select_value." ".$field_4_select_value;

Comment: Yes the $field_x_select_value->$value was my attempt at trying to have the value returned instead of the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switch`:

```
<?php
    switch ($field_3_select_value):
        case 1: $class3 = 'head-left'; break;
        case 2: $class3 = 'head-right'; break;
        default: $class3 = '';
    endswitch;

    switch ($field_4_select_value):
        case 1: $class4 = 'top'; break;
        case 2: $class4 = 'middle'; break;
        case 3: $class4 = 'bottom'; break;
        default: $class4 = '';
    endswitch;
?>
<div class="span 7 head <?php echo $class3; ?> <?php echo $class4; ?>">
```